# paypal return and IPN url with parameters

Tags: php, paypal

here is the form i am submitting for a recurring payment to paypal

```
 <form name='_xclick' id='_xclick' action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick-subscriptions'>
        <input type='hidden' name='business' value='sandboxusername@gmail.com'>
        <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='EUR'>
        <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='a3' value='5.00'>
        <input type='hidden' name='p3' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='t3' value='M'>
        <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='customerId=F5C151'>
        <input type='hidden' name='src' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='sra' value='1'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Lev haolam package'>
        <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='mydomainsuccess?pplstatus=0&customerId=F5C151'>
        <input type='hidden' name='return' value='mydomainsuccess?pplstatus=1&customerId=F5C151'>
        <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='mydomainsuccess?pplstatus=1&customerId=F5C151'>
        </form> <form name='_xclick' id='_xclick' action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>
        </form>
```

problem is when the customer comes back from paypal he does get back to the success page but im not getting back the extra parameters ... all i get is

```
?auth=AawipXhP8kGL5tRWEYuMZDowOdxbyXhwGGShlkbdAgL1wnIV5jMHw1QImcj0KmiFUyhrU6kw4mfc3fJPJ3leDZQ&form_charset=UTF-8
```

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the field rm (return method). 2 = post

```
<input type='hidden' name='rm' value='2'>
```

Than you should get back the parameters as POST.

Comment: yes, to validate the ipn you have to send the received parameters + `&cmd=_notify-validate` back to paypal via socket. Then you must parse the response string if it contains `VERIFIED`. I have an implementation in my MVC framework [here](http://code.google.com/p/red-mvc/source/browse/trunk/RedMVC/Paypal.php)

Comment: and how do i recognize an IPN call ?

Comment: It's the field `notify_url`. Take another url as `return`.

Comment: Thanks, after successfull purchase, when user  return to my site, then my script gets $_POST parameters too !!!